# Div wrap makes links wrapped in <ul> unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't figure this thing out for the life of me! I know the html is a little messy but it works for what I wanted to do. The problem here is that I can't click the links once they're wrapped in the div. I deleted the wrap and the links worked, but obviously the page layout gets messed up and the horizontal scroll doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm sure it's something obvious that I'm just missing but I can't figure it out!

Here's the css

```
div#wrap-gallery {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:-300px 0 0 0;
    height:950px;
    background:#000;
    z-index:-999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}
ul#gallery {
    background:url('LINK');
    background-size:100%;
    width:3000px;
    float:left;
    height:950px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}

ul#gallery2 {
    background:url('LINK');
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    opacity:0.6;
    width:3000px;
    float:left;
    height:950px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}

ul#bio {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:510px;
    margin-left:400px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}



ul#music {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:-215px;
    margin-left:970px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:999999;
}

ul#lyrics {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-left:1500px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:99999999999;
}

    ul#dates {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:50px;
    margin-left:1100px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:999999999999999999;
}

    ul#gallery3 {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:-425px;
    margin-left:2000px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:999999999999999999999999999;
}

    ul#store {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:160px;
    margin-left:2375px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:99999999999999999999999999999999999;
}

    ul#contact {
    font-family: 'Rock Salt', cursive;
    width:200px;
    margin-top:120px;
    margin-left:2650px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:#fff;
    z-index:9999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}


ul#gallery li{
  display:block;
}
ul#gallery li img{
  float:left;
  height:100&#37;;
}

#lightbox {
        position:fixed; 
        top:0; 
        left:0; 
        width:100%; 
        height:100%; 
        background:url(LINK) repeat; 
        text-align:center;
    }
    #lightbox p {
        text-align:right; 
        color:#fff; 
        margin-right:20px; 
        font-size:12px; 
    }
    #lightbox img {
        box-shadow:0 0 15px #111;
        -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 15px #111;
        -moz-box-shadow:0 0 15px #111;
        max-width:940px;
    }
    #content img{
      height:90%;
      max-width:100%;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {

      div#wrap-gallery {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    margin:-300px 0 0 0;
    height:1000px;
    background:#000;
    z-index:-999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}
ul#gallery {
    background:url('{image:pano}');
    background-size:100%;
    width:3000px;
    float:left;
    height:1000px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}

ul#gallery2 {
    background:url('{image:map}');
    background-size:100%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    opacity:0.6;
    width:3000px;
    float:left;
    height:1000px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
}  

    }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div id="wrap-gallery">
    <ul id="gallery">
        <ul id="gallery2">
            <ul id="bio">
                <li><a href="LINK">Bio</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="music">
                <li><a href="LINK">Music</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="lyrics">
                <li><a href="LINK">Lyrics</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="dates">
                <li><a href="LINK">Dates</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="gallery3">
                <li><a href="LINK">Gallery</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="store">
                <li><a href="LINK">Store</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="contact">
                <li><a href="LINK">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and some js:

```
var moveWin = {
    availW: 0,
    galW: 0,
    moveDis: 0,

    init: function(){
        this.availW = $(document).width();
        this.galW = $('#gallery').width() - this.availW;

        this.moveDis = this.galW / this.availW;

        $(document).mousemove(function(e){
            moveWin.displace(e);
        });
    },

    displace: function(e){
        var x = e.pageX * moveWin.moveDis;
        $('#gallery').css({left: -x});
        $('#status').html(e.pageX);
    }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    moveWin.init();

    $('.lightbox_trigger').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var image_href = $(this).attr("href");

        if ($('#lightbox').length > 0) { // #lightbox exists

            $('#content').html('<img src="' + image_href + '" />');

            //$('#lightbox').show();

            $('#lightbox').fadeIn('2000');
        }

        else { 

            var lightbox = 
            '<div id="lightbox">' +
                '<p>Click to close</p>' +
                '<div id="content">' + 
                    '<img src="' + image_href +'" />' +
                '</div>' +  
            '</div>';

            $('body').append(lightbox);
        }

    });

    $('#lightbox').live('click', function() { 
        $('#lightbox').hide();
    });

});
```

Thanks again for any help that you can offer!

Comment: Your html is invalid `ul` cannot be followed by another `ul`

Comment: Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8dzry/ Most likely it has something to do with your negative `z-index`

Comment: there is no reason to have those ridiculous z-indexes like that.

Comment: @dgig - Not to mention having z-indexes on non-positioned elements is irrelevant.